# How can I correctly form collocations such as 'cough trouble'?

Tags: nouns, collocations, compounds, adjuncts

I read a new collocation ***cough trouble*** which I could not found in any dictionary.

How can I form a *noun* + *noun* collocation?

Comment: The style of English used in newspaper headlines is famous for combining nouns without other parts of speech. It can be very distinctive. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese and http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/index.php?s=%22noun+pile%22

Answer (score 9):

The phrase you're looking for is **noun adjunct** or **adjectival noun**.  In English, we can use a noun like an adjective to modify another noun.  The second noun is the thing itself - in this case, **trouble**.  The first noun, the one that works like an adjective, tells us what kind of thing it is - in this case, **cough**, so it is **trouble regarding a cough** or **trouble about a cough**.

This is very common in English.  For example,
**apple tree** - a tree, of the type "apple"
**car door** - a door, which belongs to a car
**horse race** - a race, of horses
**race horse** - a horse, for the purpose of racing

References on noun adjuncts:
[Grammar in Use: Noun Adjuncts](http://tx.english-ch.com/teacher/chris/level-b/grammar-in-use-noun-adjuncts/)
[Noun Adjuncts (noun + noun)](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html)
[Noun as Adjective](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm)