# The combination of two nouns

Tags: word-order, nouns

I have been always having trouble with the order of nouns when I want to indicate that one describes the other.

For example, suppose I want to discuss a feature of a system named SNR (Signal-to-Noise Ratio). What is the difference between the two following sentences? Are both  correct?

> **The SNR feature** significantly affects the performance.
>
> **The feature SNR** significantly affects the performance.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't figure out the difference. What topic should I read to understand it?

As another example, suppose I want to indicate a method named XYZ.

> **The XYZ method** is more effective.

> **The method XYZ** is more effective.

Are both correct?

Comment: The word "feature" could be confusing there. It often refers to an optional aspect of a system, while SNR is an inherent characteristic. So, you could just say "The SNR affects performance." If you want to add a noun, you could say "The SNR specification".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I have edited the question and I added another example. Please see that.

Comment: I added an answer, for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

As a software developer, I'd rather use `the SNR feature`, this sounds more common.

[Also here you can find information about attributive nouns](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-when-nouns-act-like-adjectives/2998821.html):

> English often uses nouns as adjectives - to modify other nouns.

So in your example *Signal-to-Noise Ratio* is an attributive noun and is used to define **what** the feature does.

The second example is also goes in the same manner (**what** method is about):

> The XYZ method is more effective.

Just like [X-Y Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) (commonly used, so you can be sure that it is right).

Comment: I have edited the question and I added another example. Please see that.

Comment: @M.H I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Marria. Is the sentence "The method XYZ ..." incorrect?

Comment: In my opinion, it is incorrect. See the example, sometimes nouns are interchangeable with different meanings, like `car race` (race where participants use cars) and `race car` (car for the race). For `XYZ method` I cannot think of any valid construction with *method* as attributive noun. @M.H

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova - "Method efficiency" would be the efficiency of a method. Contrast with "efficiency method," which would be a method for determining (or creating) efficiency.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Yes, sure, but I meant method in binding with XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

In a compound noun, the first word usually describes the second, corresponding to the usual English word order where an adjective precedes a noun. So look at your combination and see which noun is more of a descriptor, and which is more described.

In your example "the XYZ method" is more likely than "the method XYZ", because "method" is the main noun, and "XYZ" is a further modifier or specification.

On the other hand, if you are describing a series of methods, you might go through the list like this:  method XYZ... method ABC... etc.

There are many articles available on the subject of compounds. Here's one:
[Merriam-Webster "forming compound words"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/spelling-using-compound-words-guide/the-compound)

Here's one from Stack Exchange:
[ELL How can I correctly form...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75388/how-can-i-correctly-form-collocations-such-as-cough-trouble/)